# Flutter - disable TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1, use instead TLS 1.2

Tags: android, flutter, http, tls1.2

I have a Flutter project where I send some HTTP requests. How can I disable TLS versions 1.0, 1.1 because they are no longer secure? Instead of them I want to use version 1.2.
I have attached below the code that I am using:

```
@override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
```

I have set the TLS versions 1.2 and 1.3 by calling setAlpnProtocols, but I am not sure if the 1.0 and 1.1 are not used anymore. How can I verify that now it is correct?

```
context?.setAlpnProtocols(['TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'], true);
```